# Reading a temporary properties file stored on Jenkins by the Credential Binding Plugin

Tags: java, jenkins

I use the Secret File functionality of the Credentials Binding Plugin on Jenkins:

> Copies the file given in the credentials to a temporary location, then sets the variable to that location. (The file is deleted when the build completes.)

and I'm trying the following thing:

```
String propertiesTempFilepath = "/" + System.getenv(envVariable);
InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesTempFilepath);
```

In the end, input remains null, and I'm left with a NullPointerException when I try to load a Properties object with it. Where does the plugin actually store the properties file and can I access it with the getResourceAsStream method or Java code at all?

(I would actually appreciate any advice to load that properties variable from a secret file, but I'm not familiar with writing/running shell scripts, so the main tutorial confused me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by using FileInputStream instead:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(propertiesEnvName));
```